# Placing a call programmatically though GSM Modem

Tags: api, gsm, phone-call, voice, modem

I was tasked with devising a solution to initiate a voice call using a GSM Modem programmatically. The call will be initiated via an API and play and audio file or just ring a number and then drop the call. This is to be used to notify staff during the night about critical alarms on the network.

Does anyone know of a solution or worked on something similar?

GSM network modem with SIM Card is to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the staff will appreciate an autodialer like feature, rather than a text or other message, but as this is your requirement I am guessing your customer must have already made the decision.

One good approach for which there is plenty of documentation is to use an Asterisk based solution.

If you are not familiar with it, Asterisk is a open source PBX which is capable of connecting, initiating and receiving calls.

There are several firms that made GSM/UMTS interfaces cards that you can host in a standard server/PC and use as you have described above (you want to make regular GSM voice calls not VoIP over data over a GSM model I am assuming).

Some specific info on your use case is here for example:

- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out+deliver+message

Comment: Hi Mick,
Thanks for your reply. I will research into it. Heard about Asterisks way back in the days but have not checked recent versions.